# How to speed boot up Debian 10?

Tags: debian, systemd, boot

My system boots up in approximately 1 - 1.5 minutes.

I was not able to find any way to speed the boot up.

Is there any method to do this?

Addition:

Allright, i got it, i guess.
These are the inputs.

systemd-analyze:

```
Startup finished in 10.355s (kernel) + 1min 2.918s (userspace) = 1min 13.274s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 2.902s in userspace
```

systemd-analyze blame:

```
 33.715s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 21.690s ifupdown-pre.service
 18.122s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 17.457s ModemManager.service
 16.895s snapd.service
 15.682s udisks2.service
 12.983s NetworkManager.service
 12.470s accounts-daemon.service
 11.650s dev-sda1.device
  9.820s apparmor.service
  9.391s dev-loop0.device
  8.665s vboxdrv.service
  8.664s rsyslog.service
  8.608s wpa_supplicant.service
  8.601s switcheroo-control.service
  8.597s avahi-daemon.service
  8.597s bluetooth.service
  8.594s systemd-logind.service
  8.411s dev-loop1.device
  8.075s alsa-restore.service
  4.585s networking.service
  4.467s snapd.seeded.service
  3.368s polkit.service
  1.967s exim4.service
  1.917s systemd-udevd.service
  1.713s gdm.service
  1.613s systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service
  1.266s upower.service
  1.138s keyboard-setup.service
   838ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   738ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
   734ms colord.service
   713ms dev-mqueue.mount
```

Which service(s) should i deactivate?

And when i try to use `systemctl critical-chain` command, i got this input:

`Unknown operation critical-chain.`

Comment: Just so you know, it is not normal. Just boot up and run either `journalctl --since "2 minutes ago"` or `systemd-analyze blame` or even `systemd-analyze plot > bootup.svg`. You could all of this to your question by editing it, so we can help you.

Comment: You can remove ModemManager, bluetooth (bluez package), and plymouth without problems.

Comment: One thing that may help you: The command `systemctl critical-chain` is wrong, it should be `systemd-analyze critical-chain` instead.